# Error 42601 using postgresql and dart

Tags: postgresql, dart

I get the error 42601 when using postgresql

I created the table using pgAdmin. The autogenerated code looks as follows.

```
-- Table: posts
-- DROP TABLE posts;

CREATE TABLE posts
(
  post_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  title character varying(150) NOT NULL,
  description character varying(500),
  posted_at timestamp with time zone,
  last_edited timestamp with time zone,
  "user" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  editor character varying(50),
  up_votes integer NOT NULL,
  down_votes integer NOT NULL,
  flag character varying(7),
  CONSTRAINT "PK_post_id" PRIMARY KEY (post_id),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_user" FOREIGN KEY ("user")
      REFERENCES users (login) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE posts
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I execute an insert operation with the following helper method.

```
  addPost(Map values){
    connect(uri)
    .then((conn){
      conn.execute('insert into posts values(@title, @description, now(), now(), @user, @editor, @upVotes, @downVotes, @flag', values)
      .then((_) => conn.close())
      .catchError((err){
        print('Execute error in addPost: $err');
      })
      .whenComplete(() => conn.close());
    })
    .catchError((err) => print('Error in addPost: $err'));
  }
```

where `Map values` has the form:

```
 {'title': 'Sample title', 'description': 'This is a description for a sample post', 'user': 'dartUser', 'editor': 'dartUser', 'upVotes': 0, 'downVotes': 0, 'flag': 'healthy'}
```

I'm not a postgresql expert, so this might be something trivial I just don't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the error codes for postgresql [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html). Error 42601 means a syntax error.

I suspect the cause is that you are missing a closing bracket on the 'values' clause, after @flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Also it seems that `user` is a bad choice of column name. For future reference. If you want this to actually work you need to execute something like this: `conn.execute('insert into posts(title, description, posted_at, last_edited, "user", editor, up_votes, down_votes, flag) values(@title, @description, now(), now(), @user, @editor, @upVotes, @downVotes, @flag)', values)`